# Rails 4 - Add scope to included Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this association

```
class Product
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorization

  scope :first_five, lambda { limit(5) }
end

class Category
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, through: :categorization
end
```

For each category, I want to get **first five products** using `first_five` scope defined above.

To minimize DB request, I use `includes()`

```
@categories = Category.includes(:products).all
```

But how do you add the scope to `products`? I don't want to use `default_scope` since it affects everything.

I can't find it on Google (or I just can't get the right search term for it)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new syntax for lambda scope in Rails 4 is:

```
scope :first_five, -> { limit(5) }
```

To limit to five products in your AR query, you could do:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:products).merge(Product.first_five).all
```

The `merge(Product.first_five)` is going to add a `left outer join` on the limited five products.

**Update:**

The above code as commented is going to limit the categories.  A possible solution to your original problem could be to add another `has_many...through` relation calling it `limited_products` on the `Category` model as:

```
has_many :limited_products, -> { limit(5) }, 
         through: :products, 
         source: :categorizations
```

With this `Categeory.includes(:limited_products)` should yield the expected result of limiting products to `5`.

As you've suggested, add the `source: :categorizations` option to the newly added association `limited_products`.  `source` and `class_name` should have been synonymous.  Since the association we are defining is a `has_many...through` association which ignores `class_name` option, we should be using `:source` option instead of `:class_name` option.  Other association options ignored in a `has_many...through` relation are `:primary_key` and `:foreign_key`.

Comment: Hi, I tried using `merge` but it limits the `Category` count and not the `Product` count. So it returns 5 categories, and includes all the products

Comment: The join is going to include all the products, then apply the conditions.  It's only the result you can control with limit.  The limit in the query above is getting applied to the `Category` model(was untested code, and I missed that the limit gets applied to `categories`).  You could add another `has_many :limited_products, -> { limit(5) }, through: :products` and use it instead in your index action.

Comment: I keep getting `undefined method 'class_name' for nil:NilClass` when using `Category.includes(:limited_products)`. Is it because there is no `LimitedProduct` model (class)?

Comment: @DarcCode, yes it is because of the rails trying to classify `:limited_products` to `LimitedProducts`.  The line should read `has_many :limited_products, -> { limit(5) }, through: :products, class_name: 'Product'`

Comment: Hi it works when I added the M:M join table `source: :categorizations`. So the full code is `has_many :limited_products, -> { limit(5) }, through: :products, class_name: "Product", source: :categorizations`. You can edit your answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: @DarcCode, thanks for reminding to use `source` option, which is how I should have put it in the first place.  I've updated my answer with the correct fix.  Also, in your fix, you should remove the `class_name` option as it gets ignored in `has_many...through` relation.

Answer (score 2):

```
@categories = Category.includes(:products).all
```

It will fetch all the categories and its related products. Here limit does not work for products.

Just an alternative way.
In the `Category` model

```
has_many :products, through: :categorization, limit: 5
```

Now you need to make joins onto it, like the following.

```
@categories = Category.joins(:products).all
```

It returns all the category and upon taking each category.products, it will return five products for each category.

I know it is not the answer that you are looking for. But that what I have.

**Alternative Way**

In the Category model

```
has_many :products, through: :categorization

def get_products(limit=5)
  products[0...limit]
end
```

And in the controller

```
@categories = Category.joins(:products).all

@categories.each do |category|
  products = category.get_products
  # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
end
```

You will get 5 products for each category.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Using [0...5] seems to be the easiest way. I will use this as last resort.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
class Category
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, -> { limit(5) },  through: :categorization
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this seems to limit every `Category.includes(:products)` to 5, I want to limit it only on `index` and not `show`